# which technology is best for a Facebook application Ruby on Rails or C# and ASP?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails

My friend and I want to write a Facebook application. We've narrowed down the list of possible technologies to Ruby on Rails and C# with ASP. Here are the pros and cons we've thought of.

Cons:

- ASP - proprietary tools like Visual Studio etc. cost (lots of) money. We both don't know ASP (although we're not bad at C#).
- RoR - It's scripting so might be harder to maintain. My friend doesn't know RoR at all (but he's a fairly proficient programmer so will probably be able to pick it up quickly).

Pros:

- ASP - Facebook has an official SDK for .NET.
- RoR - I know RoR. It's open source, free and has fast development time.

What says the community? Is there something we haven't thought of?

Comment: http://theoatmeal.com/comics/websites_stop See #6 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be inclined to suggest ASP.Net, not only becuase I am biased but becuase...

- Express editions of that silver lined Dev Enviroment **Visual Studio** are available
- As you said an SDK exists for ASP.Net
- The msdn can provide more than enough documentation for any proficient programmer or novice alike
- There appears to be loads of good examples on the net for developing FB apps in ASP
- ROR is ugly!

Those are my reasons :) good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

Well, i would suggest Ruby on Rails, but i am biased :)

The API also works for Ruby on Rails applications, there are even two plugins that make life easier for you. More info at [Facebooks developer wiki](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/User:Using_Ruby_on_Rails_with_Facebook_Platform). Googling will uncover tons of examples and tutorials. Walk through one of those.

I think ruby and RoR are beautiful, but hey, that's subjective i guess ;)

I also disagree with your assumption that Ruby on Rails is harder to maintain. You should use TDD/BDD in any platform and that should totally cover you.